# Clicking on the link using html unit return the same page and then become deadlock condition in java

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have recently read that through html unit we can simulate pages.

I have similar requirement for my thesis. I have to fetch all the comments of particular link into my database. I'm currently working on Yahoo news.

Let say I am using "http://news.yahoo.com/yemen-says-regional-al-qaedas-deputy-head-dead-184541137.html" link.
There are currently 125 comments in that link. 10 displays when I open the page to see more comment I have to press "More" link, then ajax request goes into server and displays 10 more comments. Now I'm using following code to fetch all the comments.

```
       String google = "http://news.yahoo.com/yemen-says-regional-al-qaedas-deputy-  head-dead-184541137.html";


        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
         HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(google);
         HtmlAnchor advancedSearchAn = (HtmlAnchor)page1.getElementById("ugccmt-view-more");


        while(true){
            if(advancedSearchAn == null){
                String text = page1.asText();
           System.out.println(text);
                break;
            }
           page1 = advancedSearchAn.click();
           advancedSearchAn = (HtmlAnchor)page1.getElementById("ugccmt-view-more");
```

Can any one suggest me what I am doing wrong in this code, because It just give me same page with first 10 comments.

Comment: Considering that you have got an AJAX request, have you considered setting an AJAX Controller(see http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork ), or performing a check before continuing that the comments have been loaded.

Comment: Lee thanks for replying but I have tried your recommended URL before posting my question. Do you have any other idea, regarding this?